# IBM DB2 Connection Failed using PHP

Tags: php, db2, odbc, db2-luw

I just installed a new IBM DB2 Express C edition. Everything is running well by using CLI command. Such db2 connect, create table, database and anything else. (No more config, fresh installed). Every test i made using CLI command doesn't need username and password, such

```
db2 connect to mydb
```

not

```
db2 connect to mydb user myuser using mypwd
```

***This reasons why i didn't fill in user and password in php connection.***

Now, assume i already installed db2 in php driver, (php.ini). Then i want to connect db2 by using PHP. I want to build an apps using db2.
My PHP connection is :

```
<?php
$database = 'sls'; // the db i created by using CLI command
$user = ''; // i left it blank because no user config when installing
$password = ''; // i left it blank because no pwd config when installing
$hostname = 'localhost';
$port = 50000; // default port ibm db2

$conn_string = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=$database;" .
  "HOSTNAME=$hostname;PORT=$port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=$user;PWD=$password;";
$conn = db2_connect($conn_string, '', '');

if ($conn) {
    echo "<h1>Connection succeeded.</h1>";
    db2_close($conn);
}
else {
    echo "<b>Connection failed.</b><br/>";
    echo db2_conn_errormsg(). '<br/>';
 ?>
```

Then i execute the php, always showing errors,

```
Connection failed.
[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL10007N Message "0" could not be retrieved. Reason code: "3". SQLCODE=-1390
```

I'm just thinking about db2 connection same as mysql, install, use localhost as hostname and connect!

Anyone could help? Every help could be appreciate.

Comment: That's not going to work; you must supply both user name and password when connecting via TCP/IP.

Comment: Hi @mustaccio , the result is still same.

Comment: @bobby To connect to a database using the ID of the current process, just use the database name in your `db2_connect` statement - i.e. Use the variant for a catalogued database as described in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.db2-connect.php)

Comment: could you tell me the php configuration, so that i can use syntax db2_connect only without tcp/ip ? @IanBjorhovde